# Is there any way to see who is prime in matchmaking?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

So as many know, Prime Matchmaking was released recently. I know that you can see if someone is prime or not if there are in your lobby, but is there any way I can see if a particular enemy member has prime as well?

Also, is there any sort of statistical indicating how many prime matchmaking players are currently enrolled?
For ex: https://csgosquad.com/ranks shows the distribution of ranks across matchmaking at the moment. Is there anything similar for prime?

Comment: AFAIK you can tell when you are in the lobby screen - the prime logo appears behind their avatar. However In game I'm not so sure. Dont quote me on this but check the scoreboard, it might show the prime emblem next to their name or badges on their

Answer (score -1):

It's still in beta...
Right now they haven't provided us with that option, we can only check it through the lobby.

Answer (score -1):

When you are in a lobby, it can show who is PRIME because it will show a icon around there name, and there is also an option for PRIME MATCHMAKING at the bottom.

Comment: OP said they knew you could see it in the lobby.  He was looking for alternatives, and perhaps a way to see your opponents status.